# me dice que hay un error de sintaxis en INSERT INTO,pero no encuentro el error

Tags: .htaccess, ms-access-2010, microsoft-office, office365, ms-access-2013

```
Private Sub Sexo_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
Dim strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Msg As String

    'Exit this sub if the combo box is cleared
    If NewData = " " Then Exit Sub

    Msg = "'" & NewData & "' No esta en la lista." & vbCr & vbCr
    Msg = Msg & "Desea añadirlo?"

    i = MsgBox(Msg, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Unknown Book Category...")
    If i = vbYes Then
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO ColegioKevinx2.1.Tipos de sexo (Sexo) " & _
        "Values ('NewData')"

        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError 'ME DICE QUE EL ERROR ESTÁ ACÁ

        Response = acDataErrAdded
    Else
        Response = acDataErrContinue
    End If
end sub
```

Comment: En general no es muy correcto poner como nombre de tabla una frase separada por espacios, precisamente por lo que te esta sucediendo. Podrias cambiar el nombre de la tabla a uno sin espacios, o quizas se pueda poner el nombre de la tabla entre comilla simple. Algo como `'ColegioKevinx2.1'.'Tipos de sexo'`. Pero vamos, se ve que te da problemas en la construccion de la sentencia SQL.

Comment: vale, ya lo he cambiado, pero sigue el mismo problema
el error sigue aquí:

 CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

Comment: Ok. Entonces prueba a mostrar por pantalla o por consola (como se haga en access) el valor de la variable `strSQL` para ver si podemos hacer mas debug.